# Is Ethereum Contract Application Binary Interface (ABI) somewhat similar to WSDL in concept? To use an enterprise software term

Tags: abi

Is Ethereum Contract Application Binary Interface (ABI) somewhat similar to WSDL in concept? Is it an accurate approximate? To use an enterprise software glossary term which could be useful in explaining to the folks who are familiar with the SOA, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a stretch.

ABI stands for an [Application Binary Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface). It is a well-defined, common word, with over 50 years of history in the computer science.